# Plot two files with different time formats

Tags: gnuplot

I've got Data from  a  Station (TimeStamp %Y-%m-%d %H:%M) which I'd like to compare with a reference file (TimeStamp: %H:%M)
The data file from the weather station has 1 entry ever Minute
The reference File has one entry every 15 Minutes.

I tried to plot both files the same axis but for some reason it doesn't work.
I also tried the (timecolumn(1, "%H:%M") command when plotting the reference file.

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
set format x "%H:%M"
`Set title '24.12.2014'`
set origin 0,0.66
"data_20141224.csv" using 1:25 axes x1y2 linewidth 1 lc rgb 'orange' w l  title 'SolarRadiation',\
"refdat.txt" using (timecolumn(1, "%H:%M")):4 axes x1y2  linewidth 1 lc rgb 'yellow' w l title 'CI Reference'
```

The 2. Plot (CI Reference) never shos up on the plot.

Weather Station Input Files:

```
2014-12-24 06:00    1.00    0.93    0.93    0.00    9   4.8 4.8 4.8 63
2014-12-24 06:01    1.00    0.93    0.93    0.00    9   4.8 4.8 4.7 63
2014-12-24 06:02    1.00    0.93    0.93    0.00    9   4.7 4.7 4.7 63
```

Reference Input File:

```
08:22   56  32  161 54  282 85  29  349
08:37   75  42  228 68  358 112 40  460
08:52   94  51  295 81  425 131 46  539
```

Thx for the Help so far
This is what i typed:

```
clear
reset
set title "24.12.2014" font "verdana,08"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
set format x "%H:%M" time
set xlabel "Time"
set ylabel "CloudinessIndex" 
set y2label "Irradiance"
set ytics (0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0)
set yrange [0:1]
set ytics nomirror
set y2range [0:1200]
set y2tics (0,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200)
set xrange ['06:00':'22:00']
set autoscale x
set nokey
set grid
#Plot:
plot s=0, "data_20141224.csv" using \
(s==0 ? (s=timecolumn(1,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),0) : (timecolumn(1,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")-s)):25 axes x1y2 linewidth 1 lc rgb 'orange' w l title 'SolarRadiation',\
"refdata.txt" using (timecolumn(1,'%H:%M')):4 axes x1y2  linewidth 1 lc rgb 'yellow' w l title 'CI Reference',
```

Still it plots only the data from the log file
:-(

Comment: Can't you just process the reference file (with `sed`) to make the timestamps the same?

Comment: Well it's a reference file for one Month. So I would prefer an easy way to compare the measured date with the reference file of each month, without editing the reference file. Is sed easy to use for this problem?

Comment: Please update the question with input samples.

Comment: gnuplot calculates everything in seconds since 1970, your reference file lands in the wrong decade, i'd say.

Comment: Okay? That's interesting. Any ideas on how I could fix this problem, without formating the TimeStamp of the reference file?

Comment: Just add or substract the necessary number of seconds in the `using` specifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it simpler: Just ignore the date part in your log file:

```
set xdate time
set timefmt "%H:%M"
set format x "%H:%M" time
plot data using 2:3, ref using 1:2
```

If your time format specifier contains a space (e.g. "%y-%m-%d %H:%M"), gnuplot renumbers the columns so that the date is only one column. Otherwise, the date part in your logfile will just be treated as its own column, containing an unused string value.

Answer (score 1):

To automatically offset the value of the first datapoint, you can do the following:

```
 plot s=0, datafile using \
    (t=$1, s==0 ? (s=t,t-s) : t-s) : 2
```

`s=0` is an assignment, gnuplot doesn't plot those. The using statement consist of a `ternary operator` (a?b:c), and two  `serial evaluation`s (the comma), returning only the last value.

To offset the date (as you only want the daytime), you have to round s down to 00:00 using the `floor()` function. 
Set the right filename and format string variables, and do

```
 plot s=0, logfile using \
      (t=timecolumn(1,fstr1), s==0 ? (s=24*3600*floor(t/24/3600),t-s) : t-s) ,\
      reffile using (timecolumn(1,fstr2)):2
```

Now you should have both datasets in your plot. Do the 'set format x fstr time` setting, decorations, etc. and you're done.

Comment: thx a lot for taking the time to help me out here. Could you be a little more specific, i looked up the tenary operator but I don't really know how to use the plot command now. timecolumn is only needed when plotting the refernece data file (%H:%M) am I right?

Comment: If you set `xdata time`, gnuplot reads x in seconds according to the format set with `set timeformat`. The timecolumn() function works without `xdata time`, because it has its own format string (since gp5.0). The output is formatted according to `set format x` etc. If you don't use `xdata time`, you have to add the keyword `time`after the format string, so gnuplot knows it's a time format string and not a regular one.

Comment: thx I'll try. I can't really get my head arround how the plot commands have to look now

Comment: ok thx. so I don't need xdata time and set format x, when using timecolumn? so the data from my weather station has %Y-%m-%d %H:%M , which I add directly into the timecolumn command and the reference data has %H:%M.  where exactly does the time go? after the format string. Sorry but I can't seem to find any timecolumn examples anywhere.

Comment: yeah i don't get it to work, could anyone write the full plot command ?

Comment: I edited my question a bit and entered the full code, I still get only the data from the log file in the plot

Comment: No, it only is the ref data. I didn't see your logfile doesn't begin at 00:00. Check the update to my answer. (Btw., there is no column 25 in your data.)